# join mysql tables and get multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having an issue with MySQL .

I have 2 Tables :

```
 Table A             Table B

 userId               userId
 name                 email
 email
```

It's a relation 1->N (1 user can have multiple emails in Table B)

Now i want to import my users into a mail program , i want to make it in 1 query instead of multiple query .

What i would like to have is the following :

user id , name , email

ex:

```
1 , John Doe , xxx@gmail.com    (This email comes from Table A)
1 , John Doe , zzz@hotmail.com  (This email comes from Table B)
```

Currently i have the following query That returns multiple row but the problem is that the fields are not the same

i get something like :

```
Table A.name , Table A.email , Table B. email  etc ..


SELECT
jos_users.userId,
jos_members_webAddress.email2,
jos_users.uniqueId,
jos_users.firstName,
jos_users.lastName,
jos_users.username,
jos_users.email


FROM
jos_users
INNER JOIN jos_members_webAddress ON jos_users.userId = jos_members_webAddress.memberId
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you have emails in two tables?

Comment: The system was made in a way that a user could have N emails .

Comment: You now have 1 email in `tableA`, N-1 emails in `tableB`. Without the email in `tableA`, you would have N emails in `tableB`, and no pesky exceptional cases in `tableA`.

Comment: You are right but the request to Add multiple email came later and email from Table A is being used for the login system .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literal answer to your question:

```
SELECT userId, name, email
FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT tableB.userId, tableA.name, tableB.email
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.userId = tableB.userId
```

Better answer to your question, unless you can give my first response in the comments with a solid answer:

Delete `email` from `tableA`, have all emails in `tableB`, then it's just the part of the answer below the `UNION`.